# Recursive update jsonb object in PostgreSQL v9.5+

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.5

I use `jsonb_set` to partially update my jsonb object in postgres.

This what the doc says about this function.

```
 jsonb_set(
   target jsonb,           # The jsonb value you're amending.
   path text[],            # The path to the value you wish to add to or change, represented as a text array.
   new_value jsonb,        # The new object, key : value pair or array value(s) to add to or change.
   create_missing boolean  # An optional field that, if true (default), creates the value if the key doesn't already exist.
                           #   If false, the path must exist for the update to happen, or the value won't be updated.
 )
```

I thought that `create_missing` (which is true by default) will cause to unexisting path appear in my jsonb object but it seem like this works only on one last step (e.g. not recursive).

the query

```
UPDATE myScheme.myTable SET data = jsonb_set(data, $1, $2, true) where id = $3;
```

will fail if `$1 = {foo,bar,baz}` and my current `data = {foo: {}}`

The question is: How to update my `jsonb` object with recursive creating unexisting subobjects in PostgreSQL v9.5+?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like that, where instead of `t` put the name of your table:

```
UPDATE t SET data = jsonb_set(data,'{foo,bar}','{"baz":{"key1":{},"key2":[2],"key3":3,"key4":"val4"}}'::JSONB);
```

Result will be:

```
SELECT jsonb_pretty(data) FROM t;

          jsonb_pretty          
--------------------------------
 {                             +
     "foo": {                  +
         "bar": {              +
             "baz": {          +
                 "key1": {     +
                 },            +
                 "key2": [     +
                     2         +
                 ],            +
                 "key3": 3,    +
                 "key4": "val4"+
             }                 +
         }                     +
     }                         +
 }
(1 row)
```

With this approach (when all structure is defined inside `new_value` parameter) you are free to create any kinds of nested elements (*arrays*, nested *documents*, *string* or *integer* values); 
On the other side, to do it in `path` parameter will be very tricky.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it seem that it's not work for me. What if my current `data = {foo: {bar: {spam: 1, more: 2, eggs: 3}}`? Don't I completely overwrite `bar` rather than add `baz` property? I have just a little assuptions abaut what I already have in `data` object, such as `bar` property will be subobject if it already exists.